# I want to maintain my email log into my personal table using oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

I am using apex_mail.send() apex mail procedure now my objective is to maintain it's log into another table.whenever email is sended from apex_mail.send() procedure it will maintain each and every entry into my table as log.

```
DECLARE
    l_body      CLOB;
    l_body_html CLOB;
BEGIN
    l_body := 'To view the content of this message, please use an HTML enabled mail client.'||utl_tcp.crlf;

    l_body_html := '<html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size:10pt;
                    margin:30px;
                    background-color:#ffffff;}

                span.sig{font-style:italic;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:#811919;}
             </style>
         </head>
         <body>'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||'<p>Thank you for your interest in the <strong>APEX_MAIL</strong> package.</p>'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||'  Sincerely,<br />'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    l_body_html := l_body_html ||'  <span class="sig">The APEX Dev Team</span><br />'||utl_tcp.crlf;
    apex_mail.send(
    p_to   => 'some_user@somewhere.com',   -- change to your email address
    p_from => 'some_sender@somewhere.com', -- change to a real senders email address
    p_body      => l_body,
    p_body_html => l_body_html,
    p_subj      => 'APEX_MAIL Package - HTML formatted message');
END;
```

Comment: Why did you tag multiple versions of APEX? Which one are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you log each call to `apex_mail.send`, create a wrapper procedure (or package) that logs the call and only use your wrapper when sending emails.

for example:

```
create or replace package my_mail as
  procedure send( ... );
  ...
end;
/

create or replace package body my_mail as
  procedure send( ... ) as
  begin
    insert into log_table (column list) values (parameter value list);
    ...
    <additional custom code>
    ...
    apex_mail.send( ... );
  end;
  ...
end;
/
```

As a side benefit of using your own wrapper, you can add extra functionality, like automatically rewriting the recipient address to a test address when in a development or UAT environment so you don't accidentally spam real users with test data.

Comment: thanks alot bro please let me know i have bit confussion You have mention two times this line as                                                                                           send(...);  <--- inside this block can i paste apex_mail.send() body two times?

Comment: sorry I missed the key word `procedure` in my pseudo code (fixed).  The idea is to create a wrapper procedure around the apex_mail.send procedure, then instead of calling apex_mail.send in your main code you call your wrapper procedure instead. You'll need to replace the elipses with appropriate code for the procedures signature and other custom code.